# Fazer uma lista sem EACH no rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loop

gostaria de saber como faço para criar uma listagem de produtos. Onde eu tenho uma parte do sitema que cria um cliente e depois posso fazer um pedido para esse cliente. ao selecionar o cliente eu posso adicionar itens a esse pedido do cliente. Perfeito depois de selecionar tudo isso. Vai ter uma parte onde preciso listar todos os itens que estao sendo ESCOLHIDOS no itens. Preciso de NOME DO PRODUTO e QUANTIDADE QUE FOI SELECIONADO.

Exemplo:
Produtos   QTD

Arroz      15
feijao     30

é esse o meu objetivo, porém nao esta acontecendo assim, porque se eu tenho outro cliente que faz o pedido de ARROZ o nome do produto se repete com a QTD. Exemplo abaixo:
Produtos   QTD

Arroz      15
feijao     30
Arroz      15
Arroz      15

Código da minha view:

```
 <div class="box-body no-padding">
<table class="table table-condensed">
  <tr>
    <th>Produto</th>
    <th>Quantidade total</th>

  </tr>
  <% @items.each do |item| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= item.product.name %></td>
      <td><%= item.product.items.sum(:qtd_product) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>            
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece por causa de como você fez o `create` do seu Product.
Se você quer uma lista só com os produtos de um certo cliente você deve modificar no controller `@products = Product.where(user: {Seu User Desejado})`

Se caso um cliente criar um pedido com Arroz e outro também com Arroz e você não quer que esses se separem, use essa lógica no `products#create`:

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  produto_ja_existente = Product.find_by(name: @product.name) 
  if produto_ja_existente
    produto_ja_existente.items.qtd_product += @product.items.qtd_product
    produto_ja_existente.save
  else
   @product.save
  end
  redirect_to products_path
end
```